# C++ Winsock slow

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets, tcp, winsock

I am trying to send a 2D array of bools using sockets. The array is 254x5, so 1270 bytes big. I send two of this arrays from 50 to 100 times a second. This is probably not a bandwidth problem since it also happen over LAN and with 127.0.0.1 and the time taken to recieve the arrays is the same when the refresh rate (the times a second the array gets sent) is 100, 50, or even 30.

Here is the code to send:

```
if (Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    std::cout << "Winsock error - Socket creation Failed!\r\n";
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
std::cout << "Enter Ip Address : ";
char ipaddress[20];
std::cin >> ipaddress;
std::cout << "Enter port number : ";
int portnumber;
std::cin >> portnumber;
struct hostent *host;
if ((host = gethostbyname(ipaddress)) == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to resolve hostname.\r\n";
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
SockAddr.sin_port = htons(portnumber);
SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = *((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

// Attempt to connect to server
if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to establish connection with server\r\n";
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


int res = send(Socket, (char*)&refresh, sizeof(refresh), 0);

if (res == sizeof(refresh))
    std::cout << "Refresh sent.";
else
{
    std::cout << res << " :("<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<WSAGetLastError();
}
char tr = 1;
setsockopt(Socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &tr, sizeof(tr));
```

Then, when I have a value to send, I do this:

```
Send (Socket, (char*)&buf, sizeof(key), 0);
```

Here to recieve:

```
SOCKADDR_IN serverInf;
serverInf.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverInf.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serverInf.sin_port = htons(8000);
int Socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    std::cout << "Winsock error - Socket creation Failed!\r\n";
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

if (bind(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)(&serverInf), sizeof(serverInf)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    std::cout << "Unable to bind socket!\r\n";
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

listen(Socket, 1);

SOCKET TempSock = SOCKET_ERROR;
SOCKADDR taddr;
while (TempSock == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    std::cout << "Waiting for incoming connections...\r\n";
    TempSock = accept(Socket, &taddr, NULL);
}

Socket = TempSock;

std::cout << "Client connected!\r\n\r\n";
int refresh;
char* pass;
char tr = 1;
setsockopt(Socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &tr, sizeof(tr));
```

And when I have data to recieve:

```
recv(sock, (char*)&t, sizeof t, MSG_WAITALL);
```

Now I know some will say that 1270 bytes, 200 times a second it's too much. Yes, it probably is because it requires 240 kb/s. But my problem isn't that. My problem is that **a single array** takes half a second to be sent. Task Manager says i'm using just 1,6 kb/s. Why doesn't winsock use all of the bandwitdh, even when I use 127.0.0.1? I also applied **TCP_NODELAY** to both the programs:

```
setsockopt(Socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &tr, sizeof(tr));
```

Someone knows why this happens? Should I use UDP? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show some real code, not just snippets that won't even compile. but you should probably start by looking at WireShark to see what's being sent packetwise.

Comment: Alright, going to edit..

Comment: http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: First, are you sure your data is transferring correctly? What types are `buf`, `key` (in `send`) and `t` in `recv`? And can you post those particular lines properly - the ones you show aren't correct.

Comment: Oh, and your use of `char` vs. `int` for `setsockopt` may be the problem : This is the preferred way: `int i = 1;
setsockopt( iSock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char*)&i, sizeof(i))`

Comment: The preferred way is to never ignore the need for error checking :)

Comment: Socket options are better set before doing any connection. However Nagle algorithm isn't likely to blame because 1270 should be greater than MSS and because Nagle is not in effect over loopback interface on Windows. I suggest looking at TCP dumps and the way  synchronization between sender and receiver work. And, BTW, 1270 B 200 times a second is definitely not too much for the loopback.

Comment: You have listen() and accept() calls at both ends?